# Не могу в Laravel сделать redirect после ajax запроса?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Программа после  успешной регистрации отправляет **ajax**  *post запрос*  в registerController,  запрос проходит *валидацию*, если все успешно должен произойти redirect .

```
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

вот мой аякс код

```
  $.ajax( {
    headers: {
     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: "register",
    data:  someData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
       console.log('success');
    },
    error: function(data) {
       console.log('error');
    }
  });
```

Проблема в том что ***после успешной валидации*** *redirect* не происходит , в место этого возвращается **error**  *со статусом 200* и с содержимым *\home* страницы:

Почему *статус 200* возвращается *как ошибка* ?

Почему возвращается *содержимое* **\home** и *не происходит* **redirect** ?

Как сделать чтобы после правильной  валидации  ***не было ошибок***, и ***произошел бы redirect***  в *\home* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, если у тебя ajax запрос к laravel, не надо делать редиректов `return redirect()`, т.к. jquery - это не `axios`, который понимает редиректы.

Во-вторых ты же сам тип данных указал. jQuery ждет нормальный `JSON` (!!!). А при редиректе laravel выдает html

Решений несколько - установи пакет `"superbalist/laravel-ajax-redirector"`, который отслеживает редиректы, если был `ajax` запрос, и отправляет статус 278 с информацией, куда редиректит. А потом уже в success коллбэке window.location = 'куда редиректить'. Другое решение - самостоятельно выдавать нужный `response()->json()`, А лучше все вместе применять.

Answer (score 1):

Так все правильно. С чего заголовок ответа должен влиять на редирект в js?  Если хотите сделать после этого редирект, то сделайте, чтобы в `registerController` метод, к которому идет запрос, отправлял просто 200, если все прошло успешно, а в js уже через `window.location.href` делайте редирект.

Comment: Отправлять просто 200 не достаточно, нужно отправлять  валидный json  потому что аякс ждет   json

Comment: аякс не ждет ничего, вы можете ему отправить пустой респонс с кодом 200.